# Как задать padding БЭМ-блоку, если нельзя?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, бэм

Я знаю, что БЭМ-блоку нельзя задавать отступы, в том числе padding. С margin все понятно, оно влияет на расположение блока, но почему нельзя задать паддинг? Если у меня, например, карточка товара, где явно видно рамку из пустого пространства вокруг контента, то первой приходит идея задать padding. Но если нельзя, как выйти из ситуации? Не задавать же каждому элементу внутри свой отступ? Микс тоже не всегда уместно использовать. Допустим, это не карточка товара, а какой-то более глобальный блок, который не является ничьим элементом, но у него явно просматривается "рамка" из пустого пространства. Например, какой-то заголовок, который содержит в себе основной текст и подзаголовок. Или сайдбар, например.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что отступы нельзя задавать?

Comment: так везде пишут...

Comment: Приводи конкретные примеры где _именно так пишут_. Возможно ты просто не так понял, что имелось ввиду.

Comment: Я это увидела у одного Youtube-блогера, а если поискать в инете, то действительно такой информации не нашла. Я и раньше искала, но думала, что под отступами подразумевается и margin, и padding. В общем, спасибо, теперь разобралась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding не относится к внешней геометрии блока и его можно задавать по БЭМ.